# Let $C(a,r)=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | (x-a)^2+y^2=r^2\}. $ Which of the following subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ are connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

1. $C(0,1) \cup C(0,2)$
2. $C(0,1) \cup C(1,3)$
3. $C(0,1) \cup C(1,1)$
4. $C(0,1) \cup C(2,1)$

My try: 1 and 2 are clearly connected but I dnt know about 3 and 4

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'd say (2) is not connected, because $C(0,1)\cap C(1,3)=\emptyset$.

Comment: Well then according to your argument 1 is also not connected?

Comment: Now that you mention it, yes. Not that it is *my* argument: it's the definition of "connected subset".

Comment: You can use that a path-connected space is connected.